# Firestore - Am I charged for documents obtained without finishing reading their data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine you perform a query and retrieve 1000 docs from the database.

`const querySnapshot = await query.get();`

If I do not execute the `.data()` method of each doc **to read their data**, would it still be treated as 1000 reads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `get()` retrieves documents from Firestore and you'll be charged N reads where N is number of documents returned by your query. The `.data()` just returns the document's data in JSON format from the snapshots.

Do note that, just creating the `query` neither retrieves the data nor charges you anything.

```
// This is just a Query
const query = db.collection('').where(...); 


// QuerySnapshot - contains the documents matching your query.
// fetches from Firestore (unless you have any offline persistence)
const querySnapshot = await query.get();


// Array of objects - parsed from the querySnapshot
const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => d.data())
```